# How to add dynamic code/ruby code inside .conf file

Tags: ruby, linux, unix, thinking-sphinx

I'm using Sphinx search engine for my application, and I would like to add ruby code inside the sphinx.conf file to update some values dynamically based on my application server hostname? Is it possible to execute the ruby code inside sphinx.conf?  Something like below

```
{
  type = mysql
  sql_host = testHost
  sql_user = test
  sql_pass = <%= D.decrypt("encrypted password") %> // Ruby CODE
  sql_db = {{database_name}}
  sql_query_pre = SET TIME_ZONE = '+0:00'
  sql_query_pre = SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 32768
  sql_query_pre = SET NAMES utf8
 }
```

Comment: Use erb template and `File.write`. Am I missing something?

Comment: I just want to execute inside .conf file directly.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no it's not possible. Sphinx is not capable of executing Ruby directly in its .conf file.

That being said, you can use environment variables to keep the password out of your config file:

```
{
  type = mysql
  sql_host = testHost
  sql_user = test
  sql_pass = $SQL_PASS
  sql_db = {{database_name}}
  sql_query_pre = SET TIME_ZONE = '+0:00'
  sql_query_pre = SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 32768
  sql_query_pre = SET NAMES utf8
 }
```

Then you can either set the environment variable in the commandline when you run Sphinx:

```
SQL_PASS="mypassword123" indexer -c /path/to/config
```

Or set it in your .bashrc:

```
export SQL_PASS="mypassword123"
```

Or set it in ruby:

```
ENV["SQL_PASS"] = "mypassword123"
```

Keep in mind that no matter what method you choose, you must set the environment variable *before* you run Sphinx.